# Use Docusign UI with Basic API plan

Tags: docusignapi

Is the option to embed the Docusign UI is available under the Basic API plan as detailed in the below link?

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embed-ui/

We don't need embedded signing but want to use the UI to prep and send the docs for e-signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Basic API plan gives you many of the eSignature features and embedded UI is possible if you can make API calls.